# Hover doesn't work on nested ul in ie9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover, internet-explorer-9, html-lists

I have [this website](http://alcappellorosso.it/) where on the left menu there's a nested menu on the "hotel" link. The submenu that appears hovering "hotel" has a gap on the left, but since in the gap the mouse hovers the nested "ul" element there are no problems in Firefox or Google Chrome. But this doesn't work in IE9 (not sure about other versions), infact I can't reach the submenu because it disappears.

Is this a known bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think it's not a bug but just some styling issue you are having. Please check that your width is set correctly (taking the padding in account)

Comment: well, there's a 20px left padding, but it's exactly the same as in Firefox or Chrome and it's working there.

Comment: Just wondering what the point of the first UL within sidebar is? It seems that that UL could be removed as it serves no purpose as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 is seeing the `<ul/>` padding-left or `<li/>` margin-left as empty content and so the mouse hover goes straight through it.
I'm not sure why it is doing this but an easy fix would be to add a repeating transparent background image or, if legacy support is not needed, add `background-color: (255, 255, 255, 0.01)`

Comment: this is actually working. The correct style is `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);`. Anyway it's a strange issue and I hope I can find a better solution instead of this workaround. But thanks very much : )

Comment: cool, glad this worked for you! I wasn't sure a transparent background would work so I went with a very slightly opaque background. Unfortunately I left the . out of my answer - added it to reduce future confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the 20px padding on the nested UL

Then give the UL a margin top of -5px

Then give the nested LI elements a margin-left of 20px

Comment: Bummer. Shot in the dark, try making your LI elements display:inline-block;