# Jquery :hover doesnt work on nested li inside ul in IE8, IE9

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, hover, jquery-hover

I have a no of webpages which involve display of widgets (majorly built on highcharts jquery). generally a widget has a export button. On its click, it opens a small menu for various exporting options.
Clicking on the export button opens the submenu but clicking outside doesn't make it go away. :(

the jquery code for the events for click on button etc. is written in a central and separate js file.
I tried attaching a mouseout/mouseleave event on the export button and then checking if the mouse is hovering my submenu. If it's not, then close the submenu. This works fine in Chrome but not in IE.

The code is

```
var $exportMenu = $("<ul id='exportMenu'></ul>").appendTo($(settings.contentSelector, this));

DxOne.Export.initialiseExportMenuItems(thisWidgetSettings.exportOptions, $exportMenu);

$exportMenu.hide();
$exportMenu.menu();

$('<a href="#" class="export" title="Export">EXPORT</a>').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    $exportMenu.show().position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom",
        of: this
    });

    $exportMenu.mouseleave(function () {
        $exportMenu.hide();
    });
    return false;
})
    .mouseout(function (e) {
    if (!($exportMenu.is(":hover")) {
        $exportMenu.hide();
    }
    })
    .appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, this));
```

Also, I tried various solutions for adding a white background colour to the ul, as mentioned in following links but in vain.

[jquery: nested tags and hover() not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534141/jquery-nested-tags-and-hover-not-working-in-ie)

[Hover doesn't work on nested ul in ie9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503013/hover-doesnt-work-on-nested-ul-in-ie9)

Please suggest a solution. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help guys.

I was finally able to figure out a solution for this problem.
The final .mouseout event that I wrote was:

.mouseout(function (e) {
                            /* Binding hover method for handling mouse in and mouse out movement for the exportMenu first and then hiding the export Menu
                               so that while hovering-in in the exportMenu, from the export button, doesn't make it vanish. */
                            $exportMenu.hover(function (e) {
                                $exportMenu.show();
                            }, function (e) {
                                $exportMenu.hide();
                            });
                            $exportMenu.hide();
                        })
                        .appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, this));

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `$` before your exportMenu try it like,

```
.mouseout(function (e) {
  if (!($exportMenu.is(":visible")) { // and use :visible instead of :hover
    //--^--- place it before exportMenu
    $exportMenu.hide();
  }
})....
```

Comment: I'm sorry. that was a wrong copy.
I have added the $ now and it still behaves the same.

Comment: Can you make an online demo for it(Specially for IE)

Comment: I'm a novice in jquery, Rohan. I'm not versed with even basic jquery fundas properly.

Answer (score 0):

IE has problems recognizing events on elements that have no content.  Add a non-breaking space inside that ul your targeting ( e.g. &nbsp ; )

Comment: Still the same problem. :(